# making an interrupted plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to make the following plot (which I made in R) using ggplot2. How do I go about doing this? (The plot has a finer resolution from 0 to 10, but coarser resolution from 10 onwards.) know how to do this in R, but I am not sure how to proceed with this in the case of ggplot2. Here is the figure obtained using base R.

[image]

To make things useful, note that i don't have that much interest in hanging on to the right-hand y-axis. 
Also, I would like to do a similar task on a pair of barplots (have the same scale, and only one y-axis. I am hoping that that approach is similar.
[image]

I would also be open to other suggestions that would make a similar plot conveying the information similarly or better.

Many thanks for suggestions!

Comment: For the upper example: Make two separate plots and combine them with gidExtra's `grid.arrange`. Alternatively, you might be happy with using `facet_wrap`/`facet_grid`. The second example: Use `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`.

Comment: Thanks! I will look for some examples. Any suggestions for an alternative way of plotting the same information?

Comment: A log-transformation of the x-axis?